# Add button with dynamic data attributes that matches row information

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, bootstrap-4

```
function getItems() {
  let name = inputVal.value;
  console.log(name);
  clearTable();
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "../php/includes/search.php",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { "name": name },
    success: function (data, status) {
      if (data == false) {
        clearTable();
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          createRow(i, data[i].name, data[i].Item_Id);
        }

        if ($('td').hasClass('cell4')) {
          $('.cell4').append('<button class="btn-addToCart btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 my-cart-btn font-weight-bold" data-summary="test" data-quantity="1"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg align-middle mr-1"></i>Add to cart</button>');
        }
      }
    },
    complete: function (data, status) {
      console.log(status);
    }
  });
}

function createRow(id, name, Item_Id) {
  let row = table.insertRow(id);

  let cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
  let cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
  let cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
  let cell4 = row.insertCell(3);

  cell1.appendChild(document.createTextNode(id));
  cell2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(name));
  cell3.appendChild(document.createTextNode(Item_Id));
  $(cell2).addClass('cell1');
  $(cell2).addClass('cell2');
  $(cell3).addClass('cell3');
  $(cell4).addClass('cell4 text-center');
}
```

This code works so far, but now I want to add data attributes to the button so it matches the row it's placed on.

I'm thinking something like this when it comes to adding the values:

```
$('.btn-addToCart').attr("data-id", Item_Id);
$('.btn-addToCart').attr("data-name", name);
```

But how can I do that dynamically so it can loop through every row and match the rows info in cell2 and cell3 and then create a button that's connected to that row? Hope you understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create the append the `<button>` in the function `createRow` along with required attributes.

```
function createRow(id, name, Item_Id) {
    ......

    var button = $('<button><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg align-middle mr-1"></i>Add to cart</button>', {
            "class": "btn-addToCart btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 my-cart-btn font-weight-bold"
        });

    button.attr("data-summary", "test");
    button.attr("data-quantity", 1);
    button.attr("data-id", Item_Id);
    button.attr("data-name", name);

    $(cell4).addClass('cell4 text-center').append(button)
}
```

and remove following statement

```
            if ($('td').hasClass('cell4')) {
              $('.cell4').append('<button class="btn-addToCart btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 my-cart-btn font-weight-bold" data-summary="test" data-quantity="1"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart fa-lg align-middle mr-1"></i>Add to cart</button>');
            }
```

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I'm looking for, but for some reason it just adds the button without any classes or data-attributes.

Comment: @Steffinho, then try with use `button.attr("data-id", Item_Id)` also updated answer

Comment: That worked, thank you! It didn't add the classes, but I fixed that with: `button.addClass("btn-addToCart btn btn-success btn-rounded btn-sm my-0 my-cart-btn font-weight-bold");`